# If cell meets condition than transmit complete row of the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code a makro, which does the following:

Check every cell in Sheet "Heatmap" from range M3 to T200 if the cell contains the string "Select" or "Progress". If yes, transmit the entire row to Sheet "Findings".

For example: Cell M5 in Sheet "Heatmap" has the value = "Please Select" --> Then Range A5:Z5 from Sheet "Heatmap" should be transmitted to Range A5:Z5 in Sheet "Findings".

I tried the following code, but I wasn't really successful...

```
Sub Findings() 
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Worksheets("Heatmap").Range("M3:T200")
If cell.Value Like "*Select*" Or cell.Value Like "*Progress*" Then
Worksheets("Findings").cell????
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Findings()
    Dim c As Range, rw As Range, v, wsF As Worksheet
    
    Set wsF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Findings")
    
    For Each rw In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Heatmap").Range("M3:T200").Rows 'loop by row
        For Each c In rw.Cells                                              '...then by cell
            v = LCase(c.Value)
            If v Like "*select*" Or v Like "*progress*" Then
                'copy values only
                With rw.EntireRow.Range("A1:Z1")'A1:Z1 is *relative* to rw
                    wsF.Cells(rw.Row, "A").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value  
                End With
                Exit For 'done with this row
            End If
        Next c 'fixed
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately the code gives a compiler error. It says 'invalid reference to Next control variable' and marks 'cell' in 'Next cell'. Any idea how to solve the error?

Comment: Fixed it by deleting 'cell' ! :) the output is correct now, but the code copies the function of the cells into the new sheet. I need to transmit the values into the sheet, so instead of 'copy' I need something like: 

wsF.Cells(rw.Row,"A").Value = rw.EntireRow.Range("A1:Z1")

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now the code gives a 'Application-defined or object-defined error' in this line: 'wsF.Cells(rw.Row, "A").Resize(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Value = .Value'. :(

Comment: Sorry it's `Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)`  - that's what I get for editing code in the browser